# How to make Sinon Fake server respond to some routes but not all of them

Tags: backbone.js, sinon

Is it possible to setup Sinon Fake Server to respond to some routes, for example /products but not /orders.

My scenario is: I am not using Sinon Fake Server for unit testing, I want to fake the server in cases where the API is not ready yet for a given area of the application. I want the application to call the real server in all cases, but when it calls /products, I want sinon to respond it for me.

I could add reference to Sinon to the product pages temporarily until I get the real API and then remove it, but ideally I would like to keep all of that isolated from the real implementation. Right now I have a UseFakeServer flag on my main.js file to determine whether sinon is on or not. My fake server has a list of RespondWith, but if a route is not found there I get a 404 instead of trying to go to the real server. fake server AutoRespond is set to true.

Not sure if it makes a difference but I am using backbone on the front end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing the API requests via HttpXMLRequest and using at least Sinon 1.3.0 you should use sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest and then you are able to filter which requests should be faked.

> When using Sinon.JS for mockups or partial integration/functional
>   testing, you might want to fake some requests, while allowing others
>   to go throught to the backend server. With filtered
>   `FakeXMLHttpRequest`s (new in Sinon 1.3.0), you can.
>
> `FakeXMLHttpRequest.useFilters` Default false. When set to true, Sinon
>   will check added filters if certain requests should be “unfaked”.
>
> `FakeXMLHttpRequest.addFilter(fn)` Add a filter that will decide whether
>   or not to fake a request. The filter will be called when xhr.open is
>   called, with the exact same arguments (method, url, async, username,
>   password). If the filter returns true, the request will not be faked.

So for example you want all requests to /products not to be handled by Sinon it would be something like

```
sinon.FakeXMLHttpRequest.useFilters = true;
sinon.FakeXMLHttpRequest.addFilter(function(method, url, async, username, password) {
    return /\/products/g.test(url);
});
```

See http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server